# Seaborn categorical plot with hue from DataFrame rows

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have this pandas DataFrame:

```
>>> print(df)
Channel     0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
Sample                                                 
7d       3.82  4.10  3.86  3.86  3.95  3.65  3.43  3.63
12d      2.97  4.32  3.50  3.58  3.22  3.37  3.58  3.78
17d      4.01  4.04  4.10  3.43  3.76  3.26  3.35  3.48
DO       3.07  3.58  3.14  3.22  3.11  3.09  3.16  3.16
```

I want to do a plot similar to this (the code is `sns.swarmplot(df)`):

[image]

But the colors should be set not per-channel (i.e. DataFrame column) but per-sample (i.e. DataFrame rows). So each "category" on the x-axis will have 4 colors corresponding to the rows 7d, 12d, 17d and DO.

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in seaborn?

**EDIT**: I should add that I tried using the `hue` keyword, but it says it requires using also `x` and `y` keyword. According to [this example](https://web.stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html?highlight=swarmplot#seaborn.swarmplot) seems that I need to create a new DataFrame with all numeric values in one column and two other columns with sample and channel information. Then I can call the plot as `sns.swarmplot(x='Channel', y='values', hue='Sample')`. Is there a more direct way that does not involve creating an additional ad-hoc DataFrame?

**EDIT2**: Following @BrenBarn suggestion, I end up creating a new "tidy" DataFrame with:

```
dd = []
for sa in df.index:
    print(sa)
    d = pd.DataFrame(df.loc[sa]).reset_index()
    d.columns = ['Channel', 'Leakage']
    d['Sample'] = sa
    dd.append(d)
ddf = pd.concat(dd)
```

And then plotting the data with:

```
sns.swarmplot(x='Channel', y='Leakage', hue='Sample', data=ddf)
```

which gives the plot I expected:

[image]

I was hoping there was a way to
tell seaborn to use original "2-D table" format to do the plot
which is much more compact and natural for this kind of data. 
If this is possible I would accept the answer ;).

Comment: Why not transpose your data?  Then you can make `Channel` a column and set it as X variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate how to make `Channel` a column and set it as X variable?

Comment: Your edit suggests you already figured out how to do it.  In general to use seaborn plots effectively you need your data in a "tidy" format, where each row represents a single observation.  You should try to get your data into that format.  Rather than thinking of it as an "additional ad hoc DataFrame", you should consider making that format your basic, all-purpose format.

Comment: Ok thanks @BrenBarn! Got your point. It's just that for this data the 2-D table is much more natural and compact form.

Answer (score 3):

You've basically answered your question in the edit, but you may want to look at
`pd.melt` or `pd.stack` as an easier way of creating your new tidy DataFrame.

e.g.

```
s=df.stack()
s.name='values'
df_tidy=s.reset_index()
sns.stripplot(data=df_tidy,hue='sample',x='Channel',y='values')
```

or

```
df_tidy=pd.melt(df.reset_index(),id_vars=['sample'],value_vars=df.columns.tolist(),value_name='values')
sns.stripplot(data=df_tidy,hue='sample',x='Channel',y='values')
```

Comment: Interesting, I was not aware of those functions! With your hint I found an even simpler way: `pd.melt(df.T.reset_index(), id_vars='Channel')`

Comment: Also, a non-seaborn alternative: `df.T.plot(marker='o',ls='None')` (at least works well for this example, I don't know how complex your actual dataset is).

Comment: Wow, your are right! I loose the "swarm" feature though.